# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lpsolve.LpSolveException

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve inequalities and would like to use Java ILP (http://javailp.sourceforge.net/). I've included javailp-1.2a.jar to the project.

However, in my code, I get error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lpsolve/LpSolveException
at net.sf.javailp.SolverFactoryLpSolve.getInternal(SolverFactoryLpSolve.java:29)
at net.sf.javailp.AbstractSolverFactory.get(AbstractSolverFactory.java:36)
```

I've included these imports:

```
import net.sf.javailp.Solver;
import net.sf.javailp.SolverFactory;
import net.sf.javailp.SolverFactoryLpSolve;
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Missed classpath configuration. Check your classpath again. IF you use some dependency management tool like Ant, Maven or Gradle, you must declare dependency.

Comment: @TuanBA I checked properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and added javailp-1.2a.jar there. And added this library to classpath.xml. However, it is throwing the same error.

Comment: @TuanBA Wait.. what do you mean by classpath configuration? Setting it in classpath.xml or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because,  native libraries are not found during execution.

One way to resolve this with the VM argument:

> -Djava.library.path="Path to lib"

More on this, the [link](https://www.eclipsezone.com//articles/eclipse-vms/) could help. [reference](https://www.eclipsezone.com//eclipse/forums/t98411.html)

Comment: I've added vm arguments. But, it still throws the same error. -Djava.library.path="/../../git/../lib/".

Answer (score 0):

It may be a 32/64 bit issue. or the library is compiled by a version newer than your java version.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17412067)

Comment: It is not a critique or clarification request. It is actually an answer if you check again the question